# Spring social and facebook api 2.4

Tags: spring, facebook, facebook-graph-api, spring-social

I'm using spring-social for facebook, `<version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>` and it works fine if I use the 2.3 Facebook version API.

I create a new app with the version 2.4 and it doesn’t work correctly, since FB changed the API policies:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/07/08/graph-api-v2.4/

> Fewer default fields for faster performance: 
>   To help improve
>   performance on mobile network connections, we've reduced the number of
>   fields that the API returns by default. You should now use the
>   `?fields=field1,field2` syntax to  declare all the fields you want the
>   API to return.

For example the post contains only the id and message and not `from-name` and `from-id`, so the class [Post](http://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/) contains only this two fields.

Now to read this value we need to add “?fields=from”.

The question is, is there a way to use spring social also with the version 2.4 ?

Comment: You should probably file a bug with the spring-social team. Have you contacted them?

Comment: No, I didn't. I solved the problem with a little workaround. But I'm sure it is not the best way.

Comment: can you please highlight it so that other viewers can use it too?

Comment: I'm in the same case, can you tell us what workaround you have used?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem persists. So, I am using as workaround the following method to bring back the fields I need:

```
Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken);

Post post = facebook.fetchObject(postId, Post.class, "picture, message, source, story, caption, place, description, type, from, link, icon, shares, created_time, name");
```